# CodeIgniter hide post id and only slug URL

Tags: codeigniter, url, blogs

I'm working on custom blog based on CodeIgniter. Got some problems at the moment I've achieved url:

/blog/view/1/my-very-first-post

I'm not happy with that I'd like to get rid off id and "/view"

That's how my controller looks like:

```
  function index($postId=null)
        {
            $this->view($postId=null);
        }


        function view($postId, $str_slug = '')
        {
                $data['title'] = ucfirst("Blog");
                $data['post'] = $this->posts->get_posts($postId);
                if($postId !== null)
                {
                        $this->load->view('templates/head', $data);
                        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                        $this->load->view('posts/single_view', $data);
                        $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data);         
                } else {
                        $this->load->view('templates/head', $data);
                        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                        $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
                        $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data);
                }

                $row = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('id' => $postId))->row();

                if ($row and ! $str_slug) {

                    $str_slug = url_title($row->title, 'dash', TRUE);
                    redirect("blog/view/{$postId}/{$str_slug}");

                }               
        }
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!!
Adam

Comment: first look at routes http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html Then look at this tutorial, scroll down to bottom for yr answer but you will probably want to look at the entire tutorial http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Comment: Will the values in the final segment of the URI be unique? Or can posts share the same slug?

Comment: @Cartalot, you gave me solution that from what I see requires storing "slug" in the DB, I'd like to avoid that

Comment: @Lefters, It won't be unique in perfect version because I'd like to load posts by ID and show up URL in address bar.

Comment: So, if someone typed `yoursite.com/blog/my-very-first-post` into their browser's address bar, how would you want that to be handled? There could, for example, be multiple posts with that slug. Removing only `view` from the URI would be relatively trivial, removing the ID would involve significantly more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the **_remap()** method. You can read more about it here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

Your code would look something like below. You still need to implement the get_posts_by_slug() method if you still need it.

```
public function _remap($slug) {
    $data['title'] = ucfirst("Blog");
    $data['post'] = $this->posts->get_posts_by_slug($slug);

    if($slug !== null)
    {
            $this->load->view('templates/head', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('posts/single_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data);         
    } else {
            $this->load->view('templates/head', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data);
    }

    $row = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug))->row();
}
```

**Update**:
Hey @AdamLesniak - it's generally good design to store a permalink to a blog post or a news article, so that it's not dependent on the title or any other volatile data structure in order to still be accessible.

But for a different approach, personally, I really think this is a nice system:

```
http://localhost/blog/my-news-article-title-permalink/3
```

The main issue is that if you don't store the slug/permalink somewhere, then you're going to feel sad when somebody changes the title of an article. Example, my article called "Hello World First Blog Post", which is accessible at:

```
http://localhost/blog/hello-world-first-blog-post
```

Changes into "First post I ever made":

```
http://localhost/blog/first-post-i-ever-made
```

So what happens to the initial URL? It's no longer accessible - any user that comes on the website via a search engine, or through somebody's link will now no longer see your comment and will instead get a 404 page, which you want to avoid.

A problem with using permalinks on their own is that you need to make sure they're unique, and extra constraints need to be set in place for that.

There are a few tricks that you can do, but they all have their pitfalls. You can for instance use the system I've mentioned above, where you stick the unique identifier at the end of the URL:

```
http://localhost/blog/hello-world/3
```

And if the title changes, you don't really care, because you're not using the slug to make your searches, but instead, you're relying on the unique identifier.

```
http://localhost/blog/first-post-i-ever-made/3
```

However I've seen opinions that this sort of system is against the idea of an URL (**Uniform** Resource Locator). I've used it in back when I was starting out, and it proved to be a flexible system; it's definitely nice to experiment with at least.

BBC do a variant of the above, by keeping the category that an article belongs to and the unique identifier for the entry:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-24511283
```

Basically, they know that an article will never change its category, although it may change its title, so they just keep the general topic, which is **business** and the unique identifier **24511283**.

In the end, what I suggest you do, as it's by far the most scalable solution is to just generate the following format:

```
http://localhost/blog/permalink/unique-id
```

The format above lets you have unique identifiers, which are important for guaranteeing singularity, and permalinks for all the search engine friendly-ness! Now if the title of the article changes, display the updated title to the user on the page, but don't do anything to the permalink, so that your URLs never change.

By also using IDs in the URL, you know for sure that you can use a permalink multiple times, and your system will still scale correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pro answer, but do you know if there is anyway to do it without storing slug URL or it's gonna be too complicated and not worth it?

Comment: Hey @AdamLesniak, I've updated my comment. Let me know if you would like some more info on the topic.

Comment: Thanks Petre for such professional and reliable answer!! I'm gonna test it tonight. Your knowledge is much appreciated!! That's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tutorial on this which may or may not help: http://www.rappasoft.com/tutorials/14-seo-friendly-links-with-codeigniter.html

Comment: wow -- thanks for posting looking forward to reading this and the ion auth tutorial.